# How to open multiple urls from a list, each in a different Firefox profile as batch

Tags: windows-7, firefox, batch

**System Info:**
Windows 7
Firefox 69.0

**Issue:**

I have a list of urls :

www.example1.com
www.example2.com
www.example3.com
*... and so forth*

I also have multiple Firefox profiles made and would like to open the urls in new windows(instances) with profiles in a batch command e.g. open www.example1.com in Profile 1, www.example2.com in Profile 2 henceforth.

**I have tried opening them singly and it works**

```
firefox -no-remote -P "my_profile" https://www.example1.com
```

But, how to do this for a list of urls taking the profiles alongwith?

I have checked this question [@SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28916807/bat-file-that-open-multiple-url-windows-with-firefox) but `-new-window` doesn't work and how to add profile?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to combine with the `-new-instance` parameter to tell Firefox to start a new instance and not merely a new window of any existing instances.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options).

> Open new instance, not a new window in running instance, which allows
>   multiple copies of application to be open at a time.
>
> `firefox -new-instance -P "Another Profile"`